# can_ok With anonymous functions

Tags: function, unit-testing, perl, testing, anonymous-function

In my module Foo.pm I got some anonymous functions, e.g.

```
our $anon = sub {
  my $parameter = shift;
  return $parameter * $parameter;
}
```

I'm using `Test::More` to write unit tests for the functions in my module.

For normal subroutines, i can use `can_ok("Foo.pm", @subs)` with `@subs` containing the subroutine names. For anonymous functions, I get the following error:

```
Foo->can('$anon') failed
```

Is there any way to dereference the functions and pass them to `can_ok()`?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to test for. can_ok('Foo.pm", "bar") is basically testing that you can call the bar() method on a Foo object, i.e. that Foo->bar() won't crash. What method do you want to test for with your anon sub? How would you call that method normally?

Comment: @DaveMitchell afaik `can_ok()` tests if a method can be called. In my example, it tests for all methods in `@subs` if they are callable. The anonymous subroutines have to be dereferenced to call them, e.g. `&$anon($parameter)`

Comment: So you essentially want to test if $Foo::anon is set to a coderef?  How about just `is(ref $Foo::anon, 'CODE')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`can`](https://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL) works by looking at inheritance and module composition to determine if a thing can execute a method. If you have package variables that contain code refs, you cannot use that sort of test. It makes no sense.

You could test whether your `$anon` gets exported correctly. In your example above you are using it without the package name, so I am assuming you are exporting it. But keep in mind [that Exporter suggests not to export variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter#What-Not-to-Export).

Instead, I would suggest checking if there is a symbol in the package, and that it's of the right type.

```perl
isa_ok $Foo::anon, 'CODE';
```

That test will fail if that symbol doesn't exist, or isn't a code reference.

To do that with a list of sub names, you can use interpolation, but you have to disable strict `refs`.

```perl
package Foo;

our $one = sub { 1 };
our $two = sub { 2 };

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

for my $sub (qw/ one two three/) {
    no strict 'refs';
    isa_ok ${ "Foo::$sub" }, 'CODE';
}

done_testing;
```

If you want anonymous methods you should probably just follow convention and name them with an underscore, such as `sub _anon`.

Comment: Is there an automated way to test this over an array? Or do i have to test every method by hand?